# New Django, SQL user here: How do I reference my database objects in code in Django?

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

I know there are tons of resources online to figure this out, but I feel like the situation with my models is very weird, and I know the syntax can get very messy, so I'm just not sure what to do.

So I am creating software for an ice cream company to track their inventory. My models look like this:

```
class sizeCounts (models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Size Count"
        verbose_name_plural = "Size Counts"

    #Just to label a collection of sizes with the corresponding flavor so it's not confusing!
    item_Flavor_Choices = [('CHOCOLATE','chocolate'),('VANILLA', 'vanilla'),('COOKIESNCREME', 'cookiesncreme'), ('STRAWBERRY', 'strawberry')]
    item_Flavor = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices = item_Flavor_Choices, default='chocolate')
    
    half_Pint_Count = models.IntegerField(default=30)
    one_Quart_Count = models.IntegerField(default=30)
    pint_Count = models.IntegerField(default=30)
    half_Gallon_Count = models.IntegerField(default=30)
    gallon_Count = models.IntegerField(default=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Half Pint: %s, Quart: %s, Pint: %s, Half Gallon: %s, Gallon: %s' % (self.half_Pint_Count, self.one_Quart_Count, 
        self.pint_Count, self.half_Gallon_Count, self.gallon_Count)


class item (models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Item"
        verbose_name_plural = "Items"

    item_Flavor_Choices = [('CHOCOLATE','chocolate'),('VANILLA', 'vanilla'),('COOKIESNCREME', 'cookiesncreme'), ('STRAWBERRY', 'strawberry')]
    item_Flavor = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices = item_Flavor_Choices)
    size_Counts = models.ForeignKey(sizeCounts, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default = None)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_Flavor
```

As you can see, I have an item model and a sizeCounts model. An item has a flavor and a set amount of quantity for each size (so a foreign key to sizeCounts). Say I have an item with the flavor being chocolate. How would I reference that object's sizeCounts? As in, how would I be able to grab a certain item object just based off of one of its attributes, and then reference the other attributes of said item object? I'd like to take this information to post the inventory on the front end.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: See [Django docs - Making queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/)...

Answer (score 0):

That is very easy, use the django queryset API to retrieve the object that you wish.

```
# Note that 'objects' is a manager and is used to make queries for a model.
item_1 = item.objects.get(item_Flavor="Chocolate")

# Then use the dot notation to access the object's fields, such as the 'attached' sizeCounts object in the size_Counts field.
item_1.size_Counts

# If you want to 'use/access' the fields/columns of the sizeCounts object, then do this:
item_1.size_Counts.half_Pint_Count # This will get you the value at this field.
```

Read up more about the Django Queryset API and object managers here:

1. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/
2. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/
3. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/managers/

Finally, consider renaming your models like this, in order to make them more identifiable as models:
SizeCount
Item